# Что означает слово "анимальтипликация"?

Tags: словообразование, существительные

Относительно недавно в комментариях под моим [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyLYA2LGTxU) на YouTube написал следующее:

*Наш еврей сделал многое в развитии историю отечественной **анимальтипликации**. Я вношу в свою ходячую энциклопедию евреев. Вечная память еврейскому земляку за наше счастливое детство.*

Что вообще означает слово ***анимальтипликация***?

Comment: в развитии историю...

Comment: "Развитие истории" — это неверно. Историю не развивают. История — это прошлое. Здесь: *сделал многое в развитии прошлого анимальтипликации*. И предлог "для" нужен.

Comment: А вы не знаете, что такое animal?